# Install php7.2-xml on nginx without apache

Tags: php, nginx, php-extension

I am trying to install `php7.2-xml` for my LEMP with nginx but the problem of `libapache2-mod-php7.2` is appearing. Strange that it is connected to apache while I use no apache but nginx. Anyway I cannot install the extension. How to install `php7.2-xml`?

```
mann@debian:~/Dropbox/deploy$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.2-xml is already the newest version (7.2.8-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libargon2-0 libc-ares2 libhttp-parser2.7.1 libuv1 nodejs-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1571 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.8-2) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mann@debian:~/Dropbox/deploy$
```

Comment: Do you see the line `php7.2-xml is already the newest version (7.2.8-2).`?

Comment: Yes. I missed it. Thanks.